# How should I fix fopen errors in OpenCart?

Tags: php

Right after installing opencart, I got these errors in admin panel:

> Warning: fopen(public_html/storagelogs/openbay.log): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u592386990/domains/hobbyland.store/public_html/system/library/log.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: fopen(public_html/storagelogs/error.log): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u592386990/domains/hobbyland.store/public_html/system/library/log.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: fopen(public_html/storagelogs/googleshopping.0.log): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u592386990/domains/hobbyland.store/public_html/system/library/log.php
>   on line 18

I already tried changing permissions to 777.

Comment: which OC version